# scala, exception handling, promises

Tags: scala

I am beginner in Scala and I have a problem with exception handling

Code

```
val f = future { throw new Exception }
val p = promise[Int]
p completeWith f
p.future onFailure  {
  case t => println("An error has occured: " + t)
}
p.future onSuccess {
  case x => println(x)
}
Await.result(f, 10 seconds)
```

and as a result I got string An error has occured: java.lang.Exception , but it is followed by an Exception and program terminates.

What is wrong with this program ?

Answer (score 5):

`Await.result` is a very blunt instrument. If the future fails, it will just throw the exception. You could skip all the lines between the first and last and you'd get the same result.

Additionally, `onFailure` doesn't provide error *handling*, properly understood—it's just a way to make something happen if the future fails. To actually handle errors, use `recover` or `recoverWith` (note that I'm using `Future` instead of `future`, which is now deprecated):

```
val f = Future { throw new Exception }

val r = f.recover {
  case t => println("An error has occured: " + t); 13 // some default value
}
```

Now you can block and wait for `r` with `Await.result(r, 10.seconds)`.

Answer (score -1):

Await will rise the exception again for you in the main thread.

if you make

```
try {
  Await.result(f, 10 seconds)
}
catch {
  case a => prinln("here")
}
```

your code will execute the println("here") line.

Comment: Sorry, but the first part is exactly what I said, and the second part is a _very_ convoluted way to handle a failed future.